# What are the default APPDATA directories each version of Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, special-folders, appdata

Is there a list of default APPDATA directories each version of Windows?  (XP & up)

I need to know the default directory each OS will return for the following call:

```
SHGetSpecialFolderLocation( NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA|CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE , &pidl );
```

Comment: Were you curious about non-English versions of Windows too? It could be a very long list.

Comment: Good question, but no.  English only at this point.

Comment: Why do you (think you) need the list? Why not use the function call?

Comment: @Alf - *I* don't need the list, my manager asked for it, and I don't want to manually seek out PC's with these OS's to find out.  Unfortunately, I can't find a list (which I assumed there would be somewhere).

Comment: Looks scarce.. for Vista it would be `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming`. Also, if it doesn't currently exist, how about making a wiki answer to this with the default ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a simple answer to make into a list even for just english installs.

Here are some examples I just pulled from a few machines.

```
Windows 8 - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming
Windows 7 - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming
2K8    -    C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming
Vista   -   C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming
XP     -    C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data
2K3    -    C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data
```

you will get different answers for when you Roam or not, when you use a remote desktop etc.

Comment: Are these Home or Professional versions? Since XP, those are distinct releases.

Comment: These are from Professional or Ultimate, don't have any home ones.